# Global variable cannot be modify in function

Tags: python, scope, global-variables

```
login_success = False


def user_login():
    login_username = input("Enter your username to login.\n")
    login_password = input("Enter your password to login.\n")

    credentials_checking = open("user_credentials.txt", "r")
    while not login_success:
        for line in credentials_checking:
            credential_element = line.split(" | ")
            if login_username == credential_element[0] and login_password == credential_element[1][:-1]:
                print("Login successful!")
            else:
                login_success = True
                break
    credentials_checking.close()
```

login_success is a global variable but unfortunately an error occur. (This project do not allow the use of global function)The output are as below:

Output:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'login_success' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: You need to say `global login_success` if you want to declare that your local assignment to `login_success` should operate on the global variable rather than creating a local variable.  (It would be better, however, to use a local variable and then `return` it to the caller so that it can have control over assigning that value in its own scope.)

Comment: Assignments create local variables unless you use the `global` statement to mark the name as global first (or the `nonlocal` statement to specify a name in an enclosing non-global scope).

Comment: The answers/comments already indicate that use of *global* is appropriate for this particular problem. However, it's worth considering that you don't really need a "flag" variable at all. Just use *while True* with a carefully placed *break*. Also, did you notice that when the user input doesn't match **anything** in user_credentials.txt that your code runs indefinitely?

Answer (score 1):

Python functions treat all variables as they haven't been created yet, you just need to add `global login_success` to the function.

```
def user_login():
    global login_success
    # all other code
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the keyword `global`. Right now, Python thinks you're trying to refer to a local variable named `login_success`. To fix this, add the following line to your function:

```
def user_login():
    global login_success
    ...
```